# Octave: Printing and Saving Plots using PDFLATEX

Tags: octave, pdflatex

I have been trying to generate plots using the script [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Printing-and-Saving-Plots.html).

But I keep getting following errors:

```
Mesa warning: couldn't open dxtn.dll, software DXTn compression/decompression unavailable
GL2PS error: Incorrect viewport (x=0, y=0, width=0, height=0)
error: gl2ps_renderer::draw: gl2psBeginPage returned GL2PS_ERROR
error: called from
    __opengl_print__ at line 172 column 7
    print at line 519 column 14
    figures at line 13 column 1
```

Online it says it is a known bug, but there is no solution listed anywhere. I am on Windows 10 machine.

My Octave version is 4.2. I have MIKTEX installed.

What am I missing?